# Can I check for a user-typed request (address bar) on the server (Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, request, server-side, address-bar

Is there a way to know whether the `request` received by the server is a request that was submitted by the user explicitly ***by typing in the address bar***.

What I'm looking for (hypothetically coding..) :

```
var httpServer = http.createServer(function (request, response)
{
   if (request.source === "address bar") {
      // do something..
   } else {
        // do something else
   }
}).listen(3000);
```

I've googled it and I've looked for it on SO as well, but didn't find anything, so thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I want to differentiate between user typed requests and all other requests. "All other requests" could be redirects, file requests, form submissions, links and basically any url request that wasn't typed by the user in the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a solid, one-shot way to do this -- just hacky work-arounds. You could try and use the [HTTP referer header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), but this isn't used in all browsers and probably isn't your best chance.

Comment: A better approach would be to distinguish single types (AJAX requests, form requests, etc) where you can send custom headers / data *yourself* and check for that individually.

Comment: So basically this can't be done. It can only be done on certain browsers and on certain cases so there is no real solution to this. OK thanks Brednan! I thought so.